# CSS: 2 Divs side by side

Tags: css

i would like to put 2 divs side-by-side inside another div. I really have no clue why this orange-colored "Content"-div is below the navi.

What did i wrong here? Thanks!

CSS:

```
#page{position:relative;width:500px;background:yellow}
#navi{position:relative;width:100px;background:red;float:left}
#content{position:relative;width:400px;background:orange;clear:left}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
<div id="navi">Navi</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w286e9dd/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w286e9dd/4/

Answer (score 2):

```
#page{position:relative;width:500px;background:yellow}
#navi{width:100px;background:red;float:left}
#content{width:400px;background:orange;float:left}
```

This is it ... just copy and paste it.

You accidentally put clear:left instead of float:left

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS as below : ( Need to change how DIVs are displayed)

```
#page{position:relative;width:500px;background:yellow}

#navi{position:relative;width:100px;background:red;float:left; display: inline-block;}
#content{position:relative;width:400px;background:orange;clear:left ; display: inline-block;}
```

JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w286e9dd/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#content{position:relative;width:400px;background:orange;float:right}
```

This achieves what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use bootstrap-like media layout.

```css
#page {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  background: yellow;
  display: table-cell;
}
#navi {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: left
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  background: orange;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">

  <div id="navi">Navi</div>
  <div id="content">Content</div>

</div>
```